# replace all spaces in specific places using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like:

```
image.id."HashiCorp Terraform Team <terraform@hashicorp.com>" 
AND  image.label."some string"."some other string"
```

I want to replace all spaces with '___' just for the strings that are surrounded with quotes, so the final string will look like:

```
  image.id."HashiCorp___Terraform___Team___<terraform@hashicorp.com>" 
    AND  image.label."some___string"."some___other___string"
```

I've tried this:

```
text = text.replace(/"(\w+\s+)+/gi, function (a) {
                return a.replace(' ', _delimiter);
            });
```

But it only replaces the first space, so i get:
 `HashiCorp___Terraform Team <terraform@hashicorp.com>`.
and `some___other string`

I'm very bad with regexp so I'm probably doing something wrong :(

Comment: Since your input looks like a programming language, here's an obligatory reminder that you cannot handle such languages with regexes alone and might be better off using a real tokenizer/parser.

Comment: @georg It's not a programming language, it's a free text string entered by a user that must follow some rules, but inside the quotes the user can put any value he wants, If you're concerned about security, the string is sanitized at the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `/"[^"]+"/g` regex to match substrings between two `"` chars and then replace whitespace chars inside a callback method:

```js
var text = 'image.id."HashiCorp Terraform Team <terraform@hashicorp.com>" \nAND  image.label."some string"."some other string"';
var _delimiter = "___";
text = text.replace(/"[^"]+"/g, function (a) {
          return a.replace(/\s/g, _delimiter);
});
console.log(text);
```

The `"[^"]+"` pattern matches a `"`, then 1 or more chars other than `"` and then a closing `"`. The `a` variable holds the match value and `a.replace(/\s/g, _delimiter)` replaces each single whitespace char inside the match value with the "delimiter".